# Extracting String from string which fit certain width

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

if i have String "Life is Good". now i need to extract some words from that string which fits on width 40. how can achieve this from objective C ?

Comment: I need on ios. can you provide me objective c code sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is correct but to fit exact 40 i have corrected <= to == so new code will be

```
 NSString *longestFitting = nil;
 NSString *orig = "Life is Good";
 UIFont *font = ...; 
 for (int i = orig.length-1 ; i > 1 ; i--) 
{
 NSString *tmp = [orig substringToIndex:i]; 
 if ([tmp sizeWithFont:font].width == 40) 
 {
   longestFitting = tmp; 
   break;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sizeWithFont:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) method in a loop, like this:

```
NSString *longestFitting = nil;
NSString *orig = "Life is Good";
UIFont *font = ...;
for (int i = orig.length-1 ; i > 1 ; i--) {
    NSString *tmp = [orig substringToIndex:i];
    if ([tmp sizeWithFont:font].width <= 40) {
        longestFitting = tmp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is correct but to fit exact 40 i have corrected one <= to == so new code will be

NSString *longestFitting = nil;
NSString *orig = "Life is Good";
UIFont *font = ...;
for (int i = orig.length-1 ; i > 1 ; i--) {
    NSString *tmp = [orig substringToIndex:i];
    if ([tmp sizeWithFont:font].width == 40) {
        longestFitting = tmp;
        break;
    }
}

Comment: @shrestha2lt8 There is a chance that you wouldn't find an exact length: `Life is` could be 42, and `Life i` could be 38.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. Unless `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated in iOS 7, use `[tmp sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName : font}]` instead.